# About condition of The Incomparability theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The Incomparability theorem: Let a commutative ring S is integral over its subring R. Suppose Q and Q' be two prime ideals of S with $ Q \subseteq Q' $ and $ Q \cap R = Q' \cap R $ then Q=Q'.

I have proved it. My question is about the condition " S is integral over R " . Can this condition dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(x)$ and $(x, y)$ are prime ideals of $k[x, y]$ where $k$ is a field, and $(x) \cap k = \{0\} = (x, y) \cap k$.

Comment: I think 2nd one should be taken (x, y) otherwise $ Q \subseteq Q' $ does not hold

Comment: @Pradip: Whoops, yea, I missed that hypothesis.